# how to call a function to auto load elements in jquery mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

What I want to do is to have my navbar HTML markup in one place ( for easy editing).
Right now my index.html body content looks like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="SomePage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar"></div>
</div>
```

and am calling the my files in the header as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

in my app.js file is where I am trying to load the nav bar.  I have tried it 2 ways

The first:

```
var NavBar = function() {
$('div[data-role="navbar"]').html('<ul>' +
    '<li><a href="#SomePage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Brand</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="#AnotherPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Flavor</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="#LastPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">Zero Nicotine</a></li>' +
    '</ul>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    NavBar();
});
```

This results in the page getting the app to show my links, but they are stack like a normal ul without the list-style

The second way I tried it was:

```
var NavBar = function() {
$('div:jqmData[role="navbar"]').html('<ul>' +
    '<li><a href="#SomePage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Brand</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="#AnotherPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Flavor</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="#LastPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">Zero Nicotine</a></li>' +
    '</ul>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    NavBar();
});
```

This results in not seeing the links at all.

How do I create a function to load the 'navbar' in one place and use the jQuery Mobile styling?

Comment: The answer is ` $('[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforecreate', function()`  Instead of `$(document).ready`  as outlined here: [link]http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html, sorry I am logged into the worn account and it wouldn't let me answer my own question for another 7 hrs

Comment: Basically what I wrote you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`document ready`** should not be used with a **`jQuery Mobile`**, it will usually trigger before page is loaded into the **`DOM`**. To find more about this topic take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Instead you should use proper **`jQuery Mobile`** page events.

I made you a working jsFiddle **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SJG8W/)**.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index', function(){       
    $('[data-role="navbar"]').html('<ul>' +
        '<li><a href="#SomePage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Brand</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="#AnotherPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">By Flavor</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="#LastPage" data-transition="fade" data-icon="none">Zero Nicotine</a></li>' +
        '</ul>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks I got it as you can see in my comment.  Just tried your method which is simular to mine and works too